# How to check the hadoop distribution used in my cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

How can I know whether my cluster has been setup using Hortonworks,Cloudera or normal installation of hadoop components?

Also how can I know the port number of various services?

Comment: Run `hadoop version`.

Comment: Ask the server administrator(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to identify hadoop distribution from port number, since Apache, Hortonworks, Cloudera distros uses different port numbers

Other options are to check for cluster management service agents (Cloudera Manager - agent start up script - `/etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent` , Hortonworks - Ambari agent start up script - `/etc/init.d/ambari-agent`, Vanilla Apache hadoop will not have any agents in the server

Another option is to check hadoop classpath, below command can be used to get the classpath.

```
`hadoop classpath`
```

Most of hadoop distributions include distro name in the classpath, If classpath doesn't contains any of below keywords, distribution/setup will be Apache/Normal installation.

```
hdp - (Hortonworks) 
cdh - (Cloudera)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to run **hadoop version** command and in output you will see, what version of Hadoop you are having and also which distribution and its version you are running with. If you will find words like cdh or hdp then cdh stands for cloudera and hdp for hortonworks.

For example, here I am having cloudera and with hadoop version command below is output. 
Here in first line Hadoop version followed by hadoop distribution and its version.

Hope this will help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Command hdfs version will give you version of the hadoop and its distribution

Comment: If you want your answer to be upvoted you need to add some details, such as an example of the output of the command, how to find the information etc...